# Python is installed many times but can't figure out why PIP install isn't supporting?

Tags: python

I see the below:

```
C:\Users\natan12\Documents\My-Work-Files\Python-Learning\New>python -m site --user-site
C:\Users\natan12\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages
```

The first one above is the directly connected to pycharm where i am working and trying to install PIP packages but I see that all the packages and python are being installed in another folder. Probably, that goes back to days when i was trying to play with it.

My aim is to install and work in the same folder as below:

```
C:\Users\natan12\Documents\My-Work-Files\Python-Learning\New>python -m site --user-site
```

But no matter what i install or try to run probably gets into the other place instead of my working directory so i am not sure how to sort out this mess.

Can someone please help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing 'pip' globally? That worked for me when trying to use pip install while working with Django. Hope this works for you too!

Comment: I am not sure how you mean to install it globally! can you share how you did it. I am a beginner in python and just trying to run some ready made scripts and even failing to do so due to the mess.

Comment: Hey I have edited the 2nd answer. It might help you. Check out the second link that I mentioned. Hope you find something useful there!